# Создать сетку дивов 20х20 с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html, запрос

Что можно сделать с этим кодом чтобы получилась сетка? Так же можете добавить свой, более правильный код для этой решения этой задачи

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset = "utf-8">
   <title>JavaScript game</title>
   <style>
   .elem {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body onLoad="clone()">
   <div id="parent">
     <div class="elem"></div>
   </div>
   <script>
   for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
     clone(i);
   };
   function clone() {
     var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
     var elem = parent.querySelector('.elem');
     var clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
     parent.appendChild(clone);
   }
   </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот небольшая реализация на `div` с помощью 2-х циклов:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var row = createRow();
  for (var k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
    createElement(row);
  };
};

function createRow() {
  var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
  var row = document.createElement('div');
  row.className = "row";
  parent.appendChild(row);
  return row;
}

function createElement(parent) {
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.className = "elem";
  parent.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  height: 27px;
}

.elem {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="parent">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.body.innerHTML = (
  "<div class=r>" +
    "<div class=c></div>".repeat(20) +
  "</div>"
).repeat(20)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.r {
  display: table-row;
}

.c {
  display: table-cell;
}

body, div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.c:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```